# How to Get Multilayer JSON object from Graphql API in Amplify React APP

Tags: json, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

Now, I'm building a social media website using React + Amplify.
And article feature is one of the main feature of it.
But now, I'm facing a difficult issue for me.

I'm trying to get such kind of JSON object from my API.

```
{
  "Article": {
    "id": "some ID",
    "title": "some String",
    "content": "some Content",
    "comments": [
      "0": {
        "comment": {
          "id": "some ID",
          "content": "some Content",
          "owner": {
            "id": "some ID",
            "name": "name",
            "avatar": "avatar"
          },
          "replys": [
            "0": {
              "reply": {
                "id": "some ID",
                "content": "some Content",
                "owner": {
                  "id": "some ID",
                  "name": "name",
                  "avatar": "avatar"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For this, I've created schemas on my backend (Amplify API) like this.

```
    type Article
      @model
      @key( name: "articleByOwner" fields: ["ownerID", "createdAt"] queryField: "articleByOwner")
      @key( name: "articleByStatus" fields: ["status", "createdAt"] queryField: "articleByStatus") {
      id: ID!
      title: String!
      content: String!
      comments: [Comment] @connection(keyName: "commentByArticle", fields: ["id"])
      createdAt: AWSDateTime!
    }
    
    type Comment
      @model
      @key(name: "commentByArticle" fields: ["articleID", "createdAt"] queryField: "commentByArticle") 
    {
      id: ID!
      content: String!
      ownerID: ID!
      owner: Userinfo @connection(fields: ["ownerID"])
      articleID: ID!
      replys: [Reply] @connection(keyName: "replyByComment", fields: ["id"])
      createdAt: AWSDateTime!
    }
    
    type Reply
      @model
      @key(name: "replyByComment" fields: ["commentID", "createdAt"] queryField: "replyByComment" ) 
    {
      id: ID!
      content: String!
      ownerID: ID!
      owner: Userinfo @connection(fields: ["ownerID"])
      commentID: ID!
      createdAt: AWSDateTime!
    }

type Userinfo @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  avatar: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

But now, I can get only until comments.

I want this to be done until owner and replyes.

current state is like this. after executing getArticle query.
This query is generated when I push my project to the cloud using "amplify push" command.

```
{
  "Article": {
    "id": "some ID",
    "title": "some String",
    "content": "some Content",
    "comments": [
      "0": {
        "comment": {
          "id": "some ID",
          "content": "some Content",
          "owner": { nextToken: null },
          "replys": { nextToken : null }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: graphql lists are arrays of objects, not objects with `indexing props` (`"0"`) containing next objects - see https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: Yes, I know it. I mean "nextToken: null" exists where the array of object have to be.

Comment: No, I mean `comments` shouldn't contain `"0"` !! - it should contain an array with elements of `comment` type, directly or in `nodes` (or `egdes`/node) - all level of graphql query must be explicitely expressed - it's hardly doable, in reality **it doesn't make any sense with this kind ("object with numeric indexed props") of lists**

Comment: Sorry, "comments" should be an array of comments. please check the question again.

Comment: sorry, just about structures [common/usual] in graphql, not question/problem directly .... graphql expected query should be `comments { items { id content } nextToken }` and data like `"comments": { "items": [ {"id": ...}, {"id": ...}], "nextToken": ... }` - `items` [usually named `nodes`] as an container - see https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/codegen#statement-depth - follow some tutorial about relations, not docs/specs only?

Comment: I've tried almost all the things on the amplify doc, but couldn't find the solution. Are you able to provide me a exact answer? at least let me know it is possible or impossible. thank you.

Comment: again, *"follow some tutorial about relations, not docs/specs only?"*